# insert text between the lines file.txt

Tags: php

I need to place the lines with comments in a txt file, you can do it and if you can how can I do? Thank you.

This is the original file

```
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text1</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text2</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text3</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text4</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text5</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text6</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text7</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text8</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text9</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text10</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text5</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text6</a><br/>
```

I would like to make comments between the lines in this way

```
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text1</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text2</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text3</a><br/>
Home text
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text4</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text5</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text6</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text7</a><br/>
Working text
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text8</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text9</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text10</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text5</a><br/>
<a href='http://example.com/text/text.txt'>text6</a><br/>
```

Comment: I would use java, c#, or some other programming language to alter the text file.

Comment: Since you have tagges it with php: Have you taken a look at the file function? You can use that to read the file into an array, and then use array_splice. When you are done you can just replace the content of the file with the array content?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I'm using php, however, are still very impractical php, can someone give me some help with an example. Thank you

Comment: You sure can put that in a text file; the question is "why?" and why aren't you using a database for this? Text files are so much work when it comes to managing them.

Comment: The unloading text file periodically by the network, and then I need then to move to a drop-down menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Inserting text into the middle of a file is somewhat difficult without storing the contents first, as it would require you to copy the things you overwrite first. You could take a look at [fseek](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) and [ftell](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftell.php) to figure it out if you must.

Here is a simple solution using [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), basically reading the whole file and then overwriting it:

```
<?php
$lines = [];
$handle = fopen('file.txt', 'r+'); // open for read + write
while ($line = fgets($handle)) { // read
    array_push($lines, $line);
    if (strpos($line, 'text3')) {
        array_push($lines, "Home text" . PHP_EOL);
    }
    if (strpos($line, 'text7')) {
        array_push($lines, "Working text" . PHP_EOL);
    }
}
rewind($handle);
foreach ($lines as $line) { // write
    fwrite($handle, $line);
}
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

I put your text into file which I named `file.txt` I also created script like this:

```
<?php
$content = explode("\n", file_get_contents('file.txt'));
$result = "";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++) {
    if ($i === 3) {
        $result .= "Home text\n";
    }
    if ($i === 7) {
        $result .= "Working text\n";
    }

    $result .= $content[$i] . "\n";
}

file_put_contents('result.txt', $result);
```

Result of this script is that You have your lines added to file programatically. Now, rules that decide how to insert those lines are up to You. I used two nasty ifs. I don't know what are your exact intenstions, but this is working example of such a task.

Comment: This would be great for me, I tried the script, but when I look at the result, the line 3 and line 7 was written the text, but on the same line with no carriage return.

Comment: @George Replace the `"\n"` (new line) to fit your specific needs. So either Mac: `"\r"`, Linux: `"\n"`, Windows: `"\r\n"`, or HTML: `"<br>"`